# How to write this regular expression to only replace url

Tags: javascript

I have this reGex to replace a youtube link with an iframe.

```
const regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
```

It works, but it replaces the whole string let say I have something like this...

> const string = `This is a youtube like video but replace just the link...
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oPAkkHXYHs&t=541s`;

It replaces the whole string variable, but I want it to only replace the

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oPAkkHXYHs&t=541s

Which should give me something like this in the end.

`This is a youtube like video but replace just the link... <iframe ...>video</iframe>`;

How can I change the regExp to replace just part of the string?

```
string = string.replace(regExp, function (url) {
                     return `<iframe ....></iframe>`;
   });
```

Comment: you need to remove the link and extract only text

Comment: What is your current `replace` function? You have the regex, but what is the replacement?

Comment: @CertainPerformance ```string.replace(regExp, function (url) {
                     return `<iframe ....></iframe>`;
   });```

Comment: it feels like this could be exploited pretty easily to show other pages inside iframes as well.. I would be reluctant to use this kind of approach against at least random users input! Perhaps from a content manager / be system.. but still you never know.. Like "Watch my funny dog here http://verybadwebsite.com#youtu.be?watch=abc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not capturing the beginning nor the end of the string, if you [put your Regex in Regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5E.*%28youtu.be%5C%2F%7Cv%5C%2F%7Cu%5C%2F%5Cw%5C%2F%7Cembed%5C%2F%7Cwatch%5C%3Fv%3D%7C%5C%26v%3D%29%28%5B%5E%23%5C%26%5C%3F%5D*%29.*) you can check that easily.

You should capture whatever comes before and after the Youtube link in capture groups (like you already did with the different parts of the link) to preserve them:

```
const regExp = /^(.*)(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*)(.*)/
```

Now you should update your replace code to take into account that the first matching group is no longer the Youtube link but whatever your string contained before it.

```js
const sourceString = 'This is a youtube like video but replace just the link... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oPAkkHXYHs&t=541s'
const regExp = /^(.*)(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*)(.*)/
const embeddedString = sourceString.replace(regExp, '$1 <iframe ...></iframe> $4')

console.log(embeddedString)
```

When you play with this a little bit you'll notice that there are a couple of issues in the original regular expressions: Youtube links containing a timestamps won't work properly as well as links containing `HTTPS` and the beginning or links to `youtube.com` instead of `youtu.be`.

> I recommend you a couple of tools that are very helpful when working
>   with regular expressions:
>
> - [Regexper](https://regexper.com/) is an online regular expression visualizer which displays a nice graph representing your regex.
> - [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is an online workbench for regular expressions which allows you to check how it is being executed on your test strings and
>     get immediate results.

That could be solved by using a simpler regex to match URLs and then a different library to extract the useful parts of the URL, like [built-in URL class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) or a third-party library.

This could also be addressed (at least partially) updating the regular expression so it extracts the video ID and ignores everything else:

```js
const sourceString = 'This is a youtube like video but replace just the link... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oPAkkHXYHs&t=541s'
const regExp = /^(.*)(?:https?)?(?:youtu\.be|youtube\.com)\/(?:v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch)(?:(?:(?:\?v=)([^& ]+)*)?)[^ ]*(.*)/
const embeddedString = sourceString.replace(regExp, '$1 <iframe ...></iframe> $3')

console.log(embeddedString)
```

Note that even though this version works fine with your sample case it is not production ready and there will be more edge cases I haven't found while writing it.

If you want to pursue the regex-based approach to this problem I suggest you try [some](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-regex) of [these](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-youtube-id) NPM packages which offer a more tested regular expression for finding the ID of a Youtube video in a link.

They may not solve your problem directly but are good start points to write a more reliable regex.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your regexp and used groups, it should work properly.

```js
const regExp = /(^.*)(http(s)?:\/\/)((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/.+/;
    
      let str = `This is a youtube like video but replace just the link... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oPAkkHXYHs&t=541s`;
    
      str = str.replace(regExp, '$1 <iframe ....></iframe>');
      console.log(str);
```